# How to use Berkeley DB's non-SQL, Key/Value API to implement fuzzy query (LIKE key word)

Tags: nosql, berkeley-db, fuzzy-search

I can understand this [Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/berkeleydb/entry/how_to_use_berkeley_dbs_non-sq), but it seems unable to apply in such case that using Berkeley DB's non-SQL, Key/Value API to implement `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%abc%'"`

```
Table structure
-------------------------------------------
key   data(name)
-------------------------------------------
0     abc
1     abcd
2     you
3     spring
.     sabcd
.     timeab
.
```

I guess iterating all records is not an efficient way, but it really do a trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct.  Absent any other tables, you'd have to scan all the entries and test each data item.  In many cases, it's as simple as this.

If you're using SQL LIKE, I doubt you'll be able to do better unless your data items have a well-defined structure.

However, if the "WHERE name LIKE %abc%" query you have is really WHERE name="abc", then you might choose to take a performance penalty on your db_put call to create a reverse index, in addition to your primary table:

```
-------------------------------------------
key(name)   data(index)
-------------------------------------------
abc          0
abcd         1
sabcd        4
spring       3
timeab       5
you          2
```

This table, sorted in alphabetical order, requires a lexical key comparison function, and uses support for duplicate keys in BDB.  Now, to find the key for your entry, you could simply do a db_get ("abc"), or better, open a cursor with DB_SETRANGE on "abc".

Depending on the kinds of LIKE queries you need to do, you may be able to use the reverse index technique to narrow the search space.

Comment: say I want to fuzzy search those strings which have "ab", but spring is in the way when iterator is running, in such case, it seems "timeab" can't be hit, that is, I just can get "abc", "abcd" and possilbe "sabcd", right?

Comment: That is right in this case.  But if "zabc" was in there, it'd be sorted last, after "you".  If you ended the search for %abc% at the first non-match, you'd miss it.